# java: cannot find a symbol when trying to use .isDigit()

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

Tried both in my IDE and in the online IDE my textbook on Zybooks.com gives me to work in. My goal is to check whether or not the variable `passCode` contains a digit. Here's the code:

```
public class CheckingPasscodes{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        boolean hasDigit = false;
        String passCode = "";
        int valid = 0;

        passCode = "abc";

        if (passCode.isDigit(passCode.charAt(0)) || passCode.isDigit(passCode.charAt(1)) || passCode.isDigit(passCode.charAt(2))) {
            hasDigit = true;
        }

        if (hasDigit) {
            System.out.println("Has a digit.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Has no digit.");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error on line 9 (where the first `if` starts):

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: method isDigit(char)
location: variable passCode of type java.lang.String
```

Tried changing `passCode.charAt(0)` (or 1 and 2) to simply `'a'` (or 'b' and 'c') to test whether it was because I was putting a method inside another method, but I seem to get the same error.

I eventually solved the problem by asking a friend, who provided me this, instead:

```
char s = passCode.charAt(0);
char s1 = passCode.charAt(1);
char s2 = passCode.charAt(2);

if ((s>'0' && s<'9') || (s1>'0' && s1<'9') || (s2>'0' && s2<'9')) {
    hasDigit=true;
}
```

It makes perfect sense, and I did think of doing something similar, but the chapter in which this exercise is isn't about `.charAt()`—we covered that before—but rather about `.isDigit()` and other character operations, so doing what I did is all but cheating.

This is driving me nuts.

P.S.: I'm pretty new to Java, so, if the answer is something really obvious, I'm really sorry. And thanks for taking your time to read all this!

Comment: @Tunaki this is not a duplicate. The accepted answer is not within the same scope as the duplicate.

Comment: You should be doing `Character.isDigit(passcode.charAt(0))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `.isDigit()` on a `String` object, which doesn't have such a method. It's a [static method of the `Character` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)).

```
Character.isDigit(passCode.charAt(0));
```

---

A big hint is that your error message stated the following:

> location: variable passCode of type java.lang.String

which should automatically prompt you to look at the [`String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the documentation on whatever method you're looking for - and, subsequently, to discover it doesn't have such a method.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.String doesnt have a isDigit method, that is only for [Char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) class...

use it as

```
boolean hasDigit = Character.isDigit('1');
```